# What is optimized for each available FitRegularization setting?

Tags: fitting

Fit and FindFit now have a FitRegularization option, but the documentation is brief. What is optimized/minimized when each available setting is used?

Comment: from [the document](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FitRegularization.html), e.g.)$||y_i-w_i x_i||+\lambda ||a||^2$,or [tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)

Comment: I agree the documentation is a bit limited but I think it's more of a statistical methodology issue than about adequacy of *Mathematica* documentation.  "What is regularization?" would be better addressed at CrossValidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  In the meantime, maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics) and https://blogs.sas.com/content/subconsciousmusings/2017/07/06/how-to-use-regularization-to-prevent-model-overfitting/ might be helpful.

Comment: I don’t have the background to follow that stuff. Examples that illustrate when and why settings for FitRegularization could be useful would be very helpful. I will ask WRI to add that to the documentation.